# Word document to CSV format

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, ms-word

I have a data in microsoft document in a tabular format which i need to convert into csv format.beacuse as far as my knowledge its easier to store values from csv to table in MS SQl server.. 
   please help me out in doing this conversion. let me know whether i can store values from word document to table itself in MS SQL 2008

Comment: What programming language do you want to use? If none is given, I always assume Malbolge.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do in Excel, but possible with the save as feature as well. 
A CSV is just a text file with commas in between the fields.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

For me, it would be easier to use a text editor than Word, but not Excel.

Comment: I have a Word file with a table copied from the internet. I tried saving it as a CSV, through an explicit conversion. It didn't work. How can I import this word file into a table?